# how to catch nodejs api data in AngularJS page?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

this is api code i am using and passing some parameters

```
app.get('/opner',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(
       path.join(__dirname, './','dist', 'index.html'),
       {user: req.session.user,value1:req.session.value1}
    );
});
```

i am serving angular with the same api.
in this case in **ejs** i can directly access this **user** and **value1**
 with **<%= user %>** like this. but how to use the same in angular app

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h4> value 1:</h4>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" ng-model="tx.data"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>user:</h4>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="tx.user"/>
</div>
```

so i want to render this page with `value1` and `user` values present.
so how to read and display in angular?

Comment: you have both `angularjs` (1.x) and `angular` (2+) tags. which one do you really use?

Comment: note : you don't have to and should not add the `"./"` in your path.join parameter.
you can direcly use `path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html')`
path.join add all `/` necessary, and __dirname is the absolute path to the current file. so as you do it, the result will be (on linux) : `"/absolute/path/.//dist/index.html"` (in window, `C:\absolute\path\./\dist\index.html`).
not exacly what I think you wanted

Comment: Maybe you have to read something about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

The node function `res.sendFile` is not the same as `res.render`.

`res.render` is for rendering EJS (or pug, or other pre-renderer).
`res.sendFile` only send file.

You cannot use the second argument of `res.sendFile` to send data alongside your index.html like you would do in EJS

The right way to do it would be to create another express route (like `/getUser`), and to send the json in this route with `res.json({req.session.user,value1:req.session.value1})`

You will then have to do a ajax request in Angular.
if you use Angular 1.x, I think the service name is `http`
for Angular 2+, the service name is `HttpClient`.

Once you have queryed the data, you can show it in your angular template like so:

```
<h4> value 1: {{tx.data}}</h4>
```

supposing you put your data on the `$scope.tx.data` object (angular 1.x) or as `this.tx = {data : data, user : user}` on the class of your component (angular 2+)

Answer (score 0):

Like Felix says is better to make your own GET route to get the data via http request, but ifyou want to avoid that you need to use a template engine (like EJS or Pug) because Angular is loaded after template rendering.

```
res.render('yourPath/index.html', {user: req.session.user, value1: req.session.value1});
```

And in your AngularJS side you can use ng-init. EJS example:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-init="tx.data = '<%= value1 %>';tx.user = '<%= user %>'">
       <h4> value 1:</h4>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" ng-model="tx.data"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <h4>user:</h4>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="tx.user"/>
    </div>
```

PUG Interpolation example:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-init="tx.data = '!{value1}';tx.user = '!{user}">
       <h4> value 1:</h4>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" ng-model="tx.data"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <h4>user:</h4>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="tx.user"/>
    </div>
```